# The output of the below code is NaN, Why?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, reduce

Here, i am trying to add 'order_total' property. I have used reduce method, if try for only arrays, the same code is working properly, but when i implemented on array of objects it is resulting NaN.

```js
var user = {
    id: 16,
    username: 'smith',
    email: 'smith@gmail.com',
    order: [
        {
            id: 71,
            order_number: 'DCT-123',
            order_total: 12000,
        },
        {
            id: 71,
            order_number: 'DCT-345',
            order_total: 7000,
        },
        {
            id: 71,
            order_number: 'DCT-321',
            order_total: 2000,
        }
    ]
};

var result = user.order.reduce(function(a, b) {
    return a.order_total + b.order_total;
}); 

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

The parameter `a` in the reduce callback is the accumulator, not the property of the object. Refer [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to learn more about reduce

```js
var user = {
    id: 16,
    username: 'smith',
    email: 'smith@gmail.com',
    order: [
        {
            id: 71,
            order_number: 'DCT-123',
            order_total: 12000,
        },
        {
            id: 71,
            order_number: 'DCT-345',
            order_total: 7000,
        },
        {
            id: 71,
            order_number: 'DCT-321',
            order_total: 2000,
        }
    ]
};

var result = user.order.reduce(function(a, b) {
    return a+b.order_total;
},0); 

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You return a number, not an object.

```
var result = user.order.reduce(function(a, b) {
    //                                  ^        object
    //                                     ^     object
    return a.order_total + b.order_total;  //    number
});
```

You need a start value of zero and add the value of the property.

```js
var user = {
    id: 16,
    username: 'smith',
    email: 'smith@gmail.com',
    order: [
        {
            id: 71,
            order_number: 'DCT-123',
            order_total: 12000,
        },
        {
            id: 71,
            order_number: 'DCT-345',
            order_total: 7000,
        },
        {
            id: 71,
            order_number: 'DCT-321',
            order_total: 2000,
        }
    ]
};

var result = user.order.reduce(function(total, a) {
    return total + a.order_total;
}, 0); 

console.log(result);
```

Comment: adding 0 is mandatory?

Comment: not mandantory, but the result of the function must match the type of the accumulator.